# How can I optimize “@llvm.global_ctors” ？

Tags: optimization, clang, llvm, clang++

I 'm working on a llvm IR code, LLVM version is 7.0.0.
here I find a variable in IR code:

```
@llvm.global_ctors = appending global [1 x { i32, void ()*, i8* }] [{ i32, void ()*, i8* } { i32 65535, void ()* @_GLOBAL__sub_I_ac_multiply.cpp, i8* null }]
```

that variable called @llvm.global_ctors is not used in IR code.
I used:
opt -std-link-opts
on this IR code, but that variable "@llvm.global_ctors" still there.

I want delete that variable, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [LLVM's language reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-global-ctors-global-variable):

> The @llvm.global_ctors array contains a list of constructor functions, priorities, and an associated global or function. The functions referenced by this array will be called in ascending order of priority (i.e. lowest first) when the module is loaded.

In your example, you cannot simply remove that variable from the IR since that would change the semantics of your program. The function `@_GLOBAL__sub_I_ac_multiply.cpp` must be called at program startup (before calling the `main` function) to perform some initialization in the code you are compiling.

Notice that this global variable does not translate to an equivalent symbol in your target binary program. Instead, it translate to whatever way your target platform uses to call the startup functions (in the case of Linux, the .ctors/.dtors/.init/.fini arrays. You can read more about them [in this great blog post](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-11-07-init-ctors-init-array)).